# Power supply cable removed from socket while upgrading to 12

Tags: upgrade, shutdown

Today I started to upgrade to ubuntu 12 when I accidentally tripped on the power supply cable and the pc shut down.

Now it displays two options. To start normal or in recovery mode but nothing works...

Do I have to format?

Answer (score 0):

Were there important files on the pc?

- if not => format, start over
- if yes => boot from liveCD see if you can mount the filesystems and recover your files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to re-install do not reformat, but at install select Something Else when given the What Do You Want To Do options, and select to install in the same partition as it currently is, but **do not** select Format.  Select / as the mount point.  This will re-install but will leave your home directories as they are, they have probably not been damaged by the power 'trip'.  That way you will not loose the options for apps that you use.  This assumes that you have not got /home in its own partition in which case all this is irrelevant.

First though do as another suggested which is to boot off live CD and backup anything important first.  Though no doubt you did this anyway before starting :)